# Are there any plans to migrate the deeplab code to tensorflow 2?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, deeplab, tensorflow-model-garden

The deeplab code under tensorflow/models/research/deeplab seems to be using the older version of tensorflow. With the new version of tensorflow out, are there any plans to migrate the existing repo to use tf2, specifically the tf2.keras api for model definition?